# Nomenclature of power functions and their graphs

Tags: polynomials, conic-sections, exponentiation

A polynomial functions of the form $$y=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots$$ is called *polynomial function of degree $n$*.

Is there a similiar nomenclature for power functions (i.e. functions of the form $y=c x^n$)?

Further the graph of the power function $y=x^2$ is a parabola. Is the graph of a general power function $y=c x^n$ called a parabola of $n$th degree or does there exists a specific name for the graphs of power functions?

Thank you for your help and I would be grateful if you could name some sources.

Comment: It is a monomial.

Comment: So you can call the function $f(x)=4x^3$ a monomial of degree 3? And how would you call its graph?

Comment: Yes.  You can call it a cubic, but of course we don't have names for all degrees.

Comment: Shouldn't it be called monomial *function*?

Comment: @garondal "*the graph of the power function $y=x^2$ is a parabola*" $\;-\;$ It is not clear what the distinction is that you mean to make here. The graph of *any* $2^{nd}$ degree polynomial function is a parabola.

Comment: @dxiv: I was just asking if, for example, the graph of $y=x^3$ is called a $3$rd degree parabobla, the graph of $y=x^4$ is called a $4$rd degree parabobla, ... . That would make sense but I'm not aware of such a notion.

Comment: "Parabola" is reserved for degree $2$.

Comment: @garondal Parabola is a [conic section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section) with a well defined geometric definition. That's a second degree algebraic curve.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.